# How do I have a number update and display live in HTML consecutively?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, element

So far I'm stuck here. I continue to get NAN as a result. I tried by starting off with a paragraph and fetching number 0 but returns "cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

```
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
 <p id="result" value=0>
      0
 </p>
 <button id="func">RUN IT</button>
 <script> 
document.getElementById("func").addEventListener("click", () => {
 var n = document.getElementById("result");
 console.log(result);
 if (n != 10) {
      n++;
      
document.getElementById("result").innerHtml = n;
 }});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `result` defined?

Comment: n is a dom element.

Comment: Isn't result defined by the value or text placed within the paragraph tag(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("func").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var n_isADomElement = document.getElementById("result");
  let v = +n_isADomElement.innerText
  
  if (v != 10) {
    v++;
    n_isADomElement.innerText = v;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<html>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <p id="result" value=0>
    0
  </p>
  <button id="func">RUN IT</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I believed n would then take the value or text assigned to the paragraphs. Is the "+" necessary for the variable? I can't find anything about it when assigning variables. Thanks again, I'm learning.
Almost forgot to mention, although it works, the console continues to show "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')".

Comment: the `+` is JS shorthand to convert a string to a number.  It's not necessary but clarifies the code, i.e. `var v="0"; v++;`  will work as long as the string can be coerced to a number. `var v= +"0"` forces the coercion on assignment.  As far as `console.log(result)`: result does not exist for you. JS is trying to log a variable called `result` which has not been defined.  If you meant to log the `innerText` of your `<p id="result">` then `console.log(getElementById("result").innerText());`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to add 10 to the result every time the button is clicked.

```js
  let result = document.querySelector('#result');
        document.querySelector('#func').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (result.textContent != 10) {
                result.textContent++
            }
        })
```

```html
<p id="result">0</p>
    <button id="func">RUN IT</button>
```

**I hope I could have helped**